# From "Handshaking Lemma" to prove a corollary that the number of edges in a complete graph is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

From "Handshaking Lemma" I wanted to prove a corollary that the number of edges in a complete graph is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.

As, we know that, $\sum_{v\in V} \deg v = 2|E| $ and for a regular graph the number of degrees of each vertices is equal to $(n-1)$, so by putting this in the sum we get (by the sum of (n-1) natural numbers 'n' times) : $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, but there is also a $2|E| $ on the R.H.S, so I'm getting the result as : $|E| = \frac{n(n-1)}{4}$, but it should be a 2 in the denominator.

What I'm doing wrong? Where I went wrong? Please help me.

Comment: I think you mean complete graph, because for a regular graph this doesn't hold

Comment: (Off-topic: I wonder if post-Covid19 textbooks will change the name of the "handshaking lemma". It does not sound fashionable right now! :-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you refer to a complete graph, because for a regular graph this doesn't hold.
For a complete graph $K_n(V, E)$ with $|V| = n$ you know that the degree of every vertex is $n-1$. Substituting this into the handshaking lemma formula one obtains
$$
2|E| = \sum_{v\in V} \text{deg}(v) = n (n-1) \iff |E| = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}
$$